# JTA vs Local transactions

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

1. Are local transactions and BMT same?
2. Do we need transactionManager for local transactions?

   I read transactionManager will be ineffective for local transactions. is that correct?
3. JTA give provision for both CMT and BMT?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in local or global transaction handling concerning BMT or CMT.

BMT and CMT only define how the start and end of transactions may be defined. In CMT it is defined by the calls of annotated methods, in BMT the start and end of transactions is defined using the UserTransaction-object.

If a global transaction is necessary or better a distributed transaction, then the Transactionmanager will arrange that, independent on BMT or CMT.

These global transactions or two phase commit become necessary as soon as more then one transaction resource is involved. For instance if you use a MessageDriven bean which calls a bean annotated as "Beanmanaged transaction handling" and doing changes in a DBMS. In that case the two-phase commit is done for both resources the message queue and the DBMS.

So, to answer your questions:

1. No, answer see above.
2. You can't do transactions with more than one resource without transactionmanager. A container providing distributed transactions as J2EE-Containers normally do, will handle all transactions using a Transactionmanager. At jboss you can configure datasources as "no jta" in that case you explicitly exempt them from two-phase commits, but I think the jboss-transactionmanager will handle the db-connections of such a datasource in spite of that.
3. Yes, if by "give provision" you mean "supports"

Answer (score 0):

Below are few points for your question in order.

1. Global transaction support is available to Web and enterprise bean J2EE components and, with some limitations, to application client
   components.

   **Enterprise bean components** can be subdivided into two categories: beans that use container-managed transactions (**CMT**),
   and those that use bean-managed transactions (**BMT**).

   A `local transaction containment (LTC)` is used to define the
   application server behavior in an unspecified transaction context.
   An LTC is a bounded unit-of-work scope, within which zero, one, or
   more resource manager local transactions (RMLT) can be accessed. The
   LTC defines the boundary at which all RMLTs must be complete; any
   incomplete RMLTs are resolved, according to policy, by the
   container. An LTC is local to a bean instance; it is not shared
   across beans, even if those beans are managed by the same container.
   LTCs are started by the container before dispatching a method on a
   J2EE component (such as an enterprise bean or servlet) whenever the
   dispatch occurs in the absence of a global transaction context. LTCs
   are completed by the container depending on the
   application-configured LTC boundary, for example, at the end of the
   method dispatch. There is no programmatic interface to the LTC
   support; LTCs are managed exclusively by the container and
   configured by the application deployer through transaction
   attributes in the application deployment descriptor.

   A local transaction containment cannot exist concurrently with a
   global transaction. If application component dispatch occurs in the
   absence of a global transaction, the container always establishes an
   LTC for J2EE components at J2EE 1.3 or later.
2. If an application uses two or more resources, an external **transaction manager** is needed to coordinate the updates to all resource managers in a global transaction.

   for more info. on **Transaction Managers** : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/EIP_Transaction_Guide/files/TxnManagers-WhatIs.html
3. BMT enterprise beans, application client components, and Web components can use the Java Transaction API (JTA) UserTransaction
   interface to define the demarcation of a global transaction. To
   obtain the UserTransaction interface, use a Java Naming and
   Directory Interface (JNDI) lookup of java:comp/UserTransaction, or
   use the getUserTransaction method from the SessionContext object.

   The UserTransaction interface is not available to **CMT** enterprise
   beans.If CMT enterprise beans attempt to obtain this interface, an
   exception is thrown, in accordance with the Enterprise JavaBeans
   (EJB) specification.

   A Web component or enterprise bean (**CMT or BMT**) can get the
   `ExtendedJTATransaction` interface through a lookup of
   `java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction`. This interface
   provides access to the transaction identity and a mechanism to
   receive notification of transaction completion.